# Cant delete disks on Google Cloud: not in ready state

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a "standard persistent disk" of size 10GB on Google Cloud using Ubutu 12.04. Whenever, I try to remove this, I encounter following error

The resource 'projects/XXX/zones/us-central1-f/disks/tahir-run-master-340fbaced6a5-d2' is not ready

Does anybody know about what's going on? How can I get rid of this disk?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently as well. I deleted an instance but the disk didn't get deleted (despite the auto-delete option being active). Any attempt to manually delete the disk resource via the dev console resulted in the mentioned error.

Additionally, the progress of the associated "Delete disk 'disk-name'" operation was stuck on 0%. (You can review the list of operations for your project by selecting compute -> compute engine -> operations from the navigation console).

I figured the disk-resource was "not ready" because it was locked by the stuck-operation, so I tried deleting the operation itself via the Google Compute Engine API (the dev console doesn't currently let you invoke the delete method on operation-resources). It goes without saying, trying to delete the operation proved to be impossible as well.

At the end of the day, I just waited for the problem to fix-itself. The following morning, I tried deleting the disk again, as it looks like the lock had been lifted in the meantime, as the operation was successful.

As for the cause of the problem, I'm still left clueless. It looks like the delete-operation was stuck for whatever reason (probably related to some issue or race-condition going on with the data-center's hardware/software infrastructure).

I think this probably isn't considered as a valid answer by SO's standards, but I felt like sharing my experience anyway, as I had a really hard time finding any info about this kind of google cloud engine problems.

If you happen to ever hit the same or similar issue, you can try waiting it out, as any stuck operation will (most likely) eventually be canceled after it has been in PENDING state for too long, releasing any locked resources in the process.

Alternatively, if you need to solve the issue ASAP (which is often the case  if the issue is affecting any resource which is crtical to your production environment), you can try:

- [Contacting Google Support](https://support.google.com/work/answer/142244?rd=1#cloud) directly (only available to paid support customers)
- Posting in the [Google Compute Engine discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gce-discussion)
- Send an email to gc-team(at)google.com to report a Production issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is the same as [the one that was solved few days ago](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=165).

If your issue didn't happen after performing those steps, you can follow Andrea's suggestion or [create a new issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/entry).

Regards,

Adrián.